# UITextField's custom font changes while in edit mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a `UITextField` that is loaded from a xib. In it's view controllers `viewDidLoad` method, I set the font to a custom value which is set up correct in the `.plist file` and everything.  It displays fine except for when it is in edit mode, at which point the font switches from my custom font to the default font, which I believe is `Helvetica`. This is jarring, and I'd like to keep the custom font throughout. I've looked around and I don't see any immediate solution, the only thing I've tried is resetting the textField.font property in the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate methods, neither of which did anything.

Edit: I've been asked for the code, it really only is one line but here goes.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        self.myTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:18];
    }
```

I've also tried resetting the font in the following two methods:

```
    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:18];
    }

    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:18];
        return YES;
    }
```

This does nothing, the font still changes while editing takes place, but then changes back to the custom font once the keyboard is dismissed.

Second edit:

Well, I just did something I probably should have tried before, and used a couple of different font files. Both of those fonts worked fine, but for whatever reason the custom font file I was using is causing the problem, despite it working normally in all other situations.

Comment: Could you post some code? I too am setting a custom font on a nib-loaded UITextField and I'm seeing this font regardless of state.

Comment: The code is pretty basic. To set a font, put this in your view controllers viewDidLoad: textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YourCustomFont" size:yourSize]; In order for this font to work, you also need to load the ttf or otf file in your info.plist file. Insert the 'Fonts Provided By Application' key, and then enter each of your font filenames as a member of the array. Of course, you also have to load the font file into your project as well.

Comment: Sorry, I can see I was unclear in my previous comment. I do know how to include custom fonts and I'm currently working on a project where I have a UITextField with a custom font that doesn't change away from this custom font when going into edit mode. So I merely wanted to suggest that you post the relevant code, that we might locate the problem.

Comment: plz paste your font name, if you want

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with an otf font (in fact I've always had problems with otf fonts...) so now I use only ttf fonts, which work great. Check out this [font converter website](http://onlinefontconverter.com/) if you need to convert fonts from otf.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:18];
}
```

Or as an alternative to fhat create an IBAction, connect it to the textField with Editing Changed and add this code to your .m:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldEditingChanged:(id)sender {
    textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:18];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything either

Comment: Ok then try settings the font in IB and not using code, doing stuff in IB always works

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the problem is with the font file.  I found that the only solution was to find an alternative font and switch.