# UITextField changes font while editing

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, uitextfield

I am suffering the same problem as here [UITextField's custom font changes while in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103560/uitextfields-custom-font-changes-while-in-edit-mode)
and could really do with a solution.

I have 4 UITextFields that I assign custom fonts in ViewDidLoad.
This works and they look great, however when clicking a field to edit the text the font changes back to default text and when resignedfirstresponder the custom font comes back.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    {

        UIFont *twoDumb = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dumb" size:20.f];

        lbl1.font = twoDumb;
        broughtForward.font = twoDumb;
        lbl2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dumb" size:24.f];
        amountTextfield.font = twoDumb;
        lbl3.font = twoDumb;
```

If I use system fonts, then the text field works as it should, so there must be something to do with this font file maybe?

Comment: what is your custom font name ????

Comment: font is 2Dumb.ttf
I'm just trying to change it but it seems to be cached somewhere as changing the name still loads the old file. Maybe i'll try a reboot.

Comment: I've deleted the font from Xcode, renamed it to just "Dumb.ttf" and put it back in Xcode. Changed my code font= to say just Dumb and renamed it in the plist, however it won't load the font. Any lines of code still saying 2Dumb WILL load the font. Very frustrating.

Comment: put some code in you question...

Comment: There's not really much code to see, but i've added it.

Comment: I've managed to rename it. I had to use a font editor to change the font family name. It's now called Dumb but the problem still remains where it switched to default text when editing the text field.

Comment: I was trying this but my font is not being loaded

Comment: File-Name and Font-Family name are totally unrelated. Changing the file-name will not lead to any changes.

Comment: Yes I know that now. I've changed the font family name and the renamed font is now working. However the issue of displaying default font while editing is still there, so font name wasn't the issue.

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103560/uitextfields-custom-font-changes-while-in-edit-mode) was asked almost an year ago. No solution found, though.

Comment: Yes I linked to that in my question.

Comment: There must be something wrong with this font. Trying other *ttf* font everything seems to be fine. Also, this problem only occurs in UITextField, if you try UITextView it displays fine during editing.

Comment: Thanks lawicko. Did you try with this 2dumb font? I wonder what could possibly be different with it and if it can be fixed.

Comment: You can try adding a method called when editDidBeging and change here the font again. I know that it's not the best solution, but if it works... (I'm not sure about that)

Comment: I will give it a go but it was tried in the other question I linked to and didn't work.

Comment: This is a known issue. File a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Known by who? I couldn't fine anything when searching apart from the other question I linked to.

Comment: @Darren: if you google +uitextfield +"custom font" you get a bunch of people having the same or similiar problems.

Comment: Thanks. I've filed a bug radar with apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The lable (lbl1,lbl2,lbl3) which you have used are custom or is it set from xib file?

I doubt the font it is changing is due to font **set in Xib file.**

[image]

Comment: The textfields (lbl1, lbl2 etc..) are added in storyboard then the font changed in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: Change the font of that  (lbl1, lbl2 etc..) in storyboard of whatever type you want. It also happened with me before. I have changed the font name in xib files of type wht i want. And it worked...

Comment: But the custom font doesn't appear in the interface builder.

Comment: then download the font,and add it to your xib files.

Comment: What do you mean? Everything i've read says you can't add custom fonts to interface builder. They must be set in code. I've added the font to my project and added it to the plist.

Comment: I am able to add the downloaded fonts.

Comment: I have just downloaded one font with name "Dumbledor_1_Wide.ttf" and able to use in interface buider

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8258/discussion-between-rupesh-and-darren)

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty for the live help you gave me. Although a solution was never found. I have filed a bug report with Apple. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have found that when I'm setting the UILabel appearance anywhere in the code:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:MYFONT];
```

Changing `UITextField` font only applies to editing text, and not to the text shown in textfield when user is not editing it.

Answer (score 2):

I have downloaded that font and tried it in an iPhone app. I also downloaded some other fonts from the internet and tried them as well. I also tried some Mac fonts such as Chalkduster. I also tried 3Dumb. The results every font I tried EXCEPT 2Dumb and 3Dumb worked. Solution: Use another font.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test. I'll have to try and find a similar font. I wonder what could possibly be different in the font to make it not work.

Comment: Perhaps just try any other font. I tested with www.WebpagePublicity.com/free-fonts/a/Aliens.ttf and it worked as expected If it doesn't for you, then you might have some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font again when editing, the font will be the same when editing.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.font = customizedFont; //The font you want to use no matter editing/no editing

}
```