# Missing fonts on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fonts

I have an ios app where i add the font file to the info.plist but it still defaults to system font.Furthermore i use a font called ChalkDuster in the IBOutlet and it also refuses to show up

Comment: You have to include that font file in your code with "the correct name which it is having after installed".

Answer (score 0):

Interface Builder can't recognize some the fonts.

see this.. Hope it will help you [Font Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359479/uitextfield-changes-font-while-editing/9463823#9463823)

Answer (score 0):

First add your font name in plist by wrirting `Fonts provided by application and add your font name in that
then you have to include ttf or otf file for dont after that yu can see that font name by this code

```
NSLog(@"Available Font Families: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);
```

from that choose your prefable font and use as below

```
[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FontName size:22] ];
```

-Thanx